# Нормально не изменяет размер изображения

Tags: php, изображения, gd

Помогите разобраться, пилю вывод картинок для og:image мета тега.
Вот мой код

```
$subtitle = (types_render_field("subtitles", array("raw" => "true" ))); 
$wpimg = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' );
$wpimg            = imagecreatefromjpeg($wpimg);

$img = imagecrop($wpimg, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => 1200, 'height' => 630]);

    $img_cover      = imagecreatefrompng("grad1.png");
    $img_logo       = imagecreatefrompng("logoog.png");
    $font_path      = "globerxbold.ttf";
    $font_path_bold = "globerxbold.ttf";
   
    $quality        = 100;

    $date           = $subtitle;
    $title          = $catname. ' '.$title;

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    | Накладываем полупрозрачный фон
    ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    imagealphablending($img, true);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    imagealphablending($img_cover, true);
    imagesavealpha($img_cover, true);    
    imagecopy($img, $img_cover, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($img_cover), imagesy($img_cover));

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    | Накладываем лого
    ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    imagealphablending($img, true);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    imagealphablending($img_logo, true);
    imagesavealpha($img_logo, true);
    imagecopy($img, $img_logo, 44, 44, 0, 0, imagesx($img_logo), imagesy($img_logo));

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    | Накладываем текст и дату
    ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $line = array(32, 64, 96);

    if (mb_strlen($title) > $line[0]) {
        $pos = mb_strlen(explode(' ', mb_substr($title, $line[0], 999), 2)[0]);
        $line[0] = $pos+$line[0];
    }
    if (mb_strlen($title) > $line[1]) {
        $pos = mb_strlen(explode(' ', mb_substr($title, $line[1], 999), 2)[0]);
        $line[1] = $pos+$line[1];
    }
    if (mb_strlen($title) > $line[0]) {
        $title = mb_substr($title, 0, $line[0])."\n".mb_substr($title, $line[0]+1, $line[1]-$line[0])."\n".mb_substr($title, $line[1]+1, $line[0]);
    }

    # Add date
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 155, 192, 239);
    $text = $date;
    imagettftext($img, 26, 0, 44, 300, $color, $font_path, $text);

    # Add City
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 15, 203, 187);
    $text = mb_strtoupper($city);
    imagettftext($img, 16, 0, 260, 151, $color, $font_path_bold, $text);

    # Add Title
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    $text = $title;
    imagettftext($img, 35, 0, 44, 360, $color, $font_path_bold, $text);

    imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Но картинки режет как-то по странному. Вот примеры:[image: Неправильная обрезка]

[image: Неправильная обрезка]

[image: правильно обрезана]

дело в том, что вордпресс в каждом посте выдает разные размеры изображения.
как мне кропать картинки в режиме «cover», что бы они заполняли все пространство?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо функции `imagecopy` используйте `imagecopyresampled`
В отличии от первой в ней дополнительно необходимо указывать результирующие ширину и высоту изображения.
Примерно так:

```
imagecopyresampled ($img, $img_cover, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1200, 630, imagesx($img_cover), imagesy($img_cover));
```